# Annualized Volatility on Backtesting.py

Tags: python

Just starting to use backtesting.py on a single strategy and trying to understand the metrics from stats.

In the output, I understand that Return = (Final Equity - Initial Equity)/Initial Equity and that Annualized Return its annualized form.

However I do not understand what is the Annualized volatility ? it seems to be neither the std from the close price of my stock for a year NEITHER the std from the ReturnPct of the trades.

I would appreciate your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the annualized volatility, of the P&L of your trading strategy.

That is, the standard deviation of the daily P&L, scaled-up to 1 year.

Hope that helps.